# NetBeans createFromTemplate Passes Wrong Value To ${name}

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I'm using code such as this in our NetBeans plugin:

```
DataObject result = dTemplate.createFromTemplate(df, name, args);
```

Which generates the file correctly. However if there is a file with the given name the template occupies a new file name (as reflected in the result object) but the `${name}` value still refers to the old name. E.g. if name = `Hi` and `Hi.java` already exists then `Hi_1.java` will be created but `${name}` will still be `Hi`.

Also I'm a bit baffled regarding the source of the `.java` extension. My original code had this:

```
DataObject result = dTemplate.createFromTemplate(df, name + ".java", args);
```

But it turns out the .java is unnecessary, and I'm not sure where I specify that this is indeed what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "right way" but this is what I have so far that seems to work:

```
private String getProperName(DataFolder f, String name, int suffix) {
    String actualName = name;
    if(suffix > 0) {
        actualName = actualName + "_" + suffix;
    }
    for(DataObject chld : f.getChildren()) {
        if(chld.getName().equals(actualName)) {
            suffix++;
            return getProperName(f, name, suffix);
        }
    }
    return actualName;
}
```

Then in the code:

```
String actualName = getProperName(df, name, 0);        
DataObject result = dTemplate.createFromTemplate(df, actualName, args);
```

That way the renaming never happens and I sort of avoid the problem.